# jquery calculate value of selected option ID with duplicate selects

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wasn't even sure how to title this right.

I have a page that needs to add the total of multiple selects and display the total anytime a select is changed.  All of the selects are named the same and the value of the options are in the ID of the option.  Everything I've tried so far has failed pretty terribly.  Thanks.

example:

```
    <select name="options">   
        <option ID="2.2" value="uid" selected>Option 1</option>
        <option ID="1.8" value="uid">Option 2</option>
        <option ID="3" value="uid">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="options">   
        <option ID="2.2" value="uid">Option 1</option>
        <option ID="1.8" value="uid" selected>Option 2</option>
        <option ID="3" value="uid">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <div id="total">Total: 4</div>
```

Comment: Storing data is what `data-` attributes for. `id` attributes are for identifying elements, which means they have to be unique.

Comment: it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: In this case i just need to use something other than the value of the option or the text of the option.  In the end I'm just passing a comma delimited list of UID's to the backend.

Comment: @renhack Why don't you put the price inside the `value` attributes (and ditch the `id` attributes)? Some browsers may break if there are multiple elements with the same ID's and/or when there are ID's which start with digits.

Comment: I can't touch the value.  This is handing off a comma separated list of UID's to a backend.  I'm just trying to add some usability to an inherited app.  I don't have access to the logic on the backend.  If there was another way without touching the value, Im all ears.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function version in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/BBhnZ/

HTML:

```
<select name="options">           
    <option data-value="2.2" value="uid" selected>Option 1</option>
    <option data-value="1.8" value="uid">Option 2</option>        
    <option data-value="3" value="uid">Option 3</option>    
</select>    

<select name="options">           
    <option data-value="2.2" value="uid">Option 1</option>        
    <option data-value="1.8" value="uid" selected>Option 2</option>        
    <option data-value="3" value="uid">Option 3</option>    

</select>    

<div id="total">Total: 4</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='options']").change(function() { updateTotal(); });
    updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
    var newTotal = 0;
    $("select[name='options'] option:selected").each(function() {
        newTotal += parseFloat($(this).data('value'));
    });
    $("#total").text("Total: " + newTotal);
}
```

Comment: hah.. .foot in mouth.   This is perfect Shane.  I didnt realize i could use the data attribute without html5 support using jquery.  Stupid on my part.

Comment: Post the code in your answer. (If jsFiddle goes down, this answer becomes useless.)

Comment: Instead of this: `.change(function() { updateTotal(); });`, just do this: `.change(updateTotal);`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Šime Vidas...  I've been busy with actual work...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var selects = $("select[name=options]");

selects.bind("change", recalculateSelectTotals);

function recalculateSelectTotals() {
    var total = 0;
    selects.find("option:selected").each(function () {
        total += Number(this.id);
    });
    $("#total").text("Total: " + total);
}
```

However, you should use `value` for values, and save ID for identifiers. Two selects with the same name is also invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

1: ID's cannot start with numbers.
2: You cannot have multiple items with the same ID
3: Give your select's classes or ID's so you can read their values `$('#selectID').val()`

Comment: I think number 3 is unnecessary. It's better for him to use a class or just the tag name, as there are more than one select element to read value from.